# MySQL Workbench: How to detach reverse-engineered EER diagram from existing database?

Tags: mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench provides the option to *'Create EER Model From Existing Database'*. Trying to remove a table from the resulting diagram leads to a dialog asking:

> Should corresponding database objects be deleted with the figures?

As the database must be left untouched in any case, my question is now: How to safely detach the EER model / diagram from the underlying database?

Comment: I haven't used Workbench for a long time but I think there are 3 separate things: the actual database, the model and the diagram(s). So, if you answer "Yes", the "database object" (i.e. the table) will be deleted from the model and not from the database itself. The model and the database are only connected/interacting when you create a model from a database or vice versa (update the database from a model). But please try these operations in a test database first (not the one with crucial data ;)

Comment: I guess I would leave the table (answer "No"), unless the table is not needed at all. If you want to use it for another diagram for example, or to connect it via FKs with other tables, keep it.

Comment: And I know I'm not really answering the question, "how to completely detach a model from the database it was created". I'm not sure if there is a way to do that, because a model can be (after created) connected to more than one server instances. (create from inst-1, change it, then create a new db in inst-2 from the changed model, then change it again, create another db in inst-3, then update the db in inst-1 with the changed model, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the table is deleted in the "model" only. The original database is not harmed. One also can filter tables via the reengineering wizard in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply answer NO to this question. It is just a confirmation if you only want to delete the figure on the canvas or the db object (in the model) as well.